# Google Tag Manager Debugging iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I pretty new to Google Tag Manager so my question could be ridiculous. I integrated GTM SDK to iOS app. In console, I see

```
GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher  persist:] 
(GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:517): Saved hit
```

I use to code snippet in below to send trigger.

```
[dataLayer push:@{
                  @"event": @"openScreen",
                  @"screenName": screenName
                  }];
```

I couldn't see any user at Google Analytics, I don't know how to debug GTM. I tried to use Charles to monitor traffic of the mobile phone and I saw that request had been sent to GTM and GA.

I don't know how to debug GTM and find where the problem is ?
Are there any debugging method for GTM?

Comment: Can you post an example of the request you saw in Charles (obfuscating your GA tracker ID)?

Comment: Now I'm using firebase SDK to send events to GoogleTagManager. I'm able to see events that are sent by firebase on Firebase Analytics console. However, I could not find a detail documentation about how GA, GTM and Firebase are working together. For example, as far as I can see firebase sends some default events like first_open but can we use them in GA?

Comment: Hey, did you find answers to your queries?

Comment: Any updates? Trying to do the same a year later, but no success